# How to install a package for latex in linux

Tags: packages, installing, linux

When I compile my `tex` file in linux using `latex filename`, I get the error that `changepage.sty` is missing. How should I install the package?

thanks a lot.

Comment: It depends on your Linux version and your TeX installation (from Linux repositories, or TeX Live). Which is it?

Comment: SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11
PATCHLEVEL = 3

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can I find out about Tex installation? (It is not my own system, I do not know how they have installed it)

Comment: @Pegah `pdftex --version` will give us a reasonable clue, also `command -v pdftex`

Comment: pdfTeX using libpoppler 3.141592-1.40.3-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.6)
kpathsea version 3.5.6
Copyright 2007 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Kpathsea is copyright 2007 Karl Berry and Olaf Weber.
Primary author of pdfTeX using libpoppler: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Kpathsea written by Karl Berry, Olaf Weber, and others.

Compiled with libpng 1.2.31; using libpng 1.2.31
Compiled with zlib 1.2.3; using zlib 1.2.7
Compiled with xpdf version 3.01

Comment: @JosephWright should be from Linux repositories.

Comment: If you don't have admin rights on the machine, might be easiest to download the package from CTAN and install it into your TEXMFHOME tree.

Comment: @cfr thanks for your answer. I have admin rights. What is the other way?

Comment: Then the best thing to do is to install the relevant package in the same way you installed other parts of TeX Live i.e. using your distro's package manager, if that's how you installed TeX Live. Which package this is depends on how the maintainers have bundled up different bits of TeX Live, I'm afraid.